# How can I return pass and return variables in a stateless conditional external react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I want to fire some variables to a stateless function and return them inside of the existing class based code.

This is my `Home` component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import External from '/External';

class Home extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        External(true);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      External(false);
    }

    render(){
      return (
        <div className="homePage pageWrapper">
            Hello
        </div>
      )
    }

}


export default Home;
```

This is my External component that will be used on many pages. I wish to reuse the functionality of it.

```
const External = ({}) => {
    if(true){
        return console.log('yes');
        // do something to the DOM
    } else {
        return console.log('no');
    }
};
```

I tried making it `this.External()` and I have tried `External('true')` to pass text but this does not work either. The console only gives a warning

`Line 2:  'External' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no-unused-vars` ESLint warning indicates actual problem with code. `External` is not exported and so isn't used.

It should be either default export:

```
export ({}) => ...
```

and

```
import External from '/External';
```

Or named export:

```
export const External = ({}) => ...
```

and

```
import { External } from '/External';
```

Comment: Can I still pass and read variables, example `External('hi')` and then I would do `const External = ({msg}) => { alert (msg) }`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You need to have `External` exported, it won't work like `const External = ...`.

Comment: External is just some external function. Can I pass variables to that function and trigger an alert for example. How would I pass parameters etc?

Comment: You can pass arguments to it as to any other function.

Comment: Can you write me an example? `export ({string, string}) => ...` this would work? like my `msg` comment

Comment: The answer already contains the example. Did it work for you? `export` has limited syntax variations, all of them are covered by the reference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export . `export ({string, string}) => ... ` is not among them and thus is not a correct one.

Comment: This worked: `export const TransparentNav = (nav) => { if (nav==="on") {`